# How can I get the object items in Axios?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

This may seem stupid, but I'm trying to access my variable in the object to log in, but I can't.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "Id": 1,
    "password": "1111111",
    "userName": "x@xx.xx",
    "userType": "Admin",
  },
  Object {
    "Id": 2,
    "password": "1234567",
    "userName": "deneme@xx.xx",
    "userType": null,
  },
]
```

If I need to show from this example, I need to reach the **userName** and **password** fields to compare on the login side.

**I try this one;**

```
axios.get('foo')
     .then(function (response) {   
       console.log(response.data.userName)
     });
```

**I try this one;**

```
axios.post('foo', {
            userName: values.email,
            password: values.password
          }).then(user => {
            if(user.userName === values.email && user.password == values.password) {
              navigation.navigate("Home");
            } else {
              console.log(user.data.username)
              Alert.alert("Warning!",
                          "Please check your email or password", 
                          [{ text: 'Ok' }]);
            }
          }).catch(function (error){
            console.warn(error.message)
          });
```

**I try this one;**

```
const userData = {
  email: values.email,
  password: values.password,
}

axios.get('foo', userData)
     .then(res => {
       responseData = res.data;
       if(responseData.status == 'success') {
         const user = responseData.user;
         navigation.navigate("Main");
       } else {
         alert('Something went wrong while login account');
       }
     });
```

**All I need is to access the username and password fields on the object.**

Comment: your response is an `Array` of `Objects`. If you want to access the `Objects` in your `Array`, use `map()`, `forEach` or simple `for` loop.

Comment: `response.data.userName` is not good. If you want to take first userName and password you should `response.data[0].userName; response.data[0].password`

Comment: I don't want to get the first user. I want to check if the logged in user is in the database @GiovanniEsposito

Comment: How can I loop in react native? @nithinpp

Comment: @developerysn `response.data.forEach(user => { /*here you have the particular user*/ })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, It doesn't make sense to validate the user credentials on the client side or comparing inside the api response for each user. Do this at the server side.

Send the user credentials information through the api and return the user object in case of true credentials or false/null in case of wrong credentials and then just check in the api response like below

```
axios.post('foo', {
            userName: values.email,
            password: values.password
          }).then((response) => {
            if(response.user){
              //here user is either the user object or null
              //credentials are correct
            }else{
              //credentials are wrong
            }
          }).catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

At the server end, you might do something like this

```
1. Get email and password from the api request
2. Verify something the credentials with the Database record 
3. Return the response with user object or null/false in case of incorrect credentials
```